# pass data to laravel markdown with events

Tags: laravel-5

Im using events to trigger an event to send emails to the user, but im getting an error when i tried to pass extra data.

Order.php

```
    protected $events = [
       'created' => Events\NewOrder::class
    ];
```

NewOrder.php

```
use App\Order;
class NewOrder
{
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


   public $order;


   public function __construct(Order $order)
   {
     $this->order = $order;
   }


   public function broadcastOn()
   {
     return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
   }
}
```

the Listener:

```
 public function handle(NewOrder $event)
 {

    Mail::to(Auth::user()->email)->send( new UserOrder( $event->pedido));
 }
```

UserOrder.php

```
 public function __construct(Order $order)
 {
    $this->order = $order;
    $id_order = $order->id;
    $details = DB::table('order_product')
            ->where('order_id', '=', $id_order)
            ->get();
    $this->$details = $details;
 }


 public function build()
 {
    return $this->markdown('emails.userorder')->with('details', $this->details);
 }
```

> Markdown mail: userorder

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
 {{ $detail->description }} 
@endforeach
```

gave me this error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$this->$details = $details;
```

to

```
$this->details = $details;
```

Also be sure that variable is declared above the __construct method, like so

```
public $details; //or protected $details;
```

Comment: dummy error.. works fine but it doesnt print the results in markdown

Comment: if no further errors occur, try `dd($details)` inside ur constructor method, maybe query result is empty after all.